# Effects of "lock(obj) { /* empty */ }" on Thread Visibility

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Given the code:

```
object sync = new object();
string result = null;

var thread = new Thread(() => {
   var workResult = DoSomeWork();
   lock (sync) { result = workResult; }
});

thread.Start();
thread.Join();

lock (sync) {
   // No code in here - not 'atomic' wrt the thread
   // as the thread has been terminated and joined.
}

// Is it SAFE to access the `result` here?
UseResultFromThread(result);
```

Does the *empty* `lock` ensure a happens-before with respect to thread visibility of the value of `result`, which is set from within the thread?

If not (and even if so), is there a better approach than using `lock` here given the previously established thread lifetime ordering?

Or (and the Y question) is the `Join` sufficient for thread visibility of the modified variable(s)?

Comment: The Join() is sufficient, no need for an extra lock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will work, yes, as entering a lock involves a memory barrier.  You could use `Thread.MemoryBarrier` instead to *just* do that.  Performance would be almost identical, it would be mostly to improve semantics for the reader.

That said, the whole thing becomes a lot easier if you use tasks instead, as they're specifically designed to represents operations that have a result, and they will take care of the appropriate synchronization when accessing that result.  Your code could be written as simply:

```
var result = Task.Run(() => DoSomeWork()).Result;
UseResultFromThread(result);
```

Of course, there isn't even much point in creating a new thread to do some work if you're only going to wait for it to finish.  At that point you might as well just have the original thread do the work and not bother with a second thread in the first place; that greatly simplifies the whole thing:

```
UseResultFromThread(DoSomeWOrk());
```

And done.

Comment: Thanks. While I'd prefer to use Tasks in general .. there is some, uhh, resistance to that change. The fuller context involves the threaded code being called from an HTTP request (the Z problem) where it's a polled Join(timeout) also checking IsClientConnected.

Comment: From the MemoryBarrier documentation I see "MemoryBarrier *is required only on multiprocessor systems with weak memory ordering* (for example, a system employing multiple Intel Itanium processors)." But yet on x86 there is still thread visibility issues.

Comment: @user2864740 The Microsoft runtime, which is specifically designed for only certain types of processors, has a stricter memory model than the C# specs actually mandate, and that is used in other runtimes for other types of hardware, so particular implementations of C# won't need the memory barrier, but if you aren't restricting your code to just those systems and need to support any C# implementation then that won't do.